# Regression of the difference between 2 poulations in the same variable and a third variable

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, nonlinear-regression

I want to perform a simple linear regression.
I have the color indices of red flower and blue flower (E.g. red could have a number between 5 to 50 of how red it is, and blue, on the same scale, of how blue it is). I collected 36 red flower and 40 blue (dep. var.). 
I am interested in the difference of color which should be one variable (between blue and red, which makes sense in my study) and i want to do regression between this difference of color spectrum variable and the sun light that the flowers got, which is a third variable (Indep. var.). 
How can i do that?
PS: each of those flowers have a sun light length score.
PPS: The variables are all continuous.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I did a regression analysis of the red and blue color as one variable with each data point as it is (Meaning that i treated color as one variable and sunshine as another, and did a simple linear regression analysis) but i am thinking that this is wrong since the R^2 resulting form this analysis would not be extrapolated either of the populations red or blue.

Then i did the regression analysis, but i added a new variable with binary code 1 for blue and 0 for red and added it as a fixed factor and color as dependent variable and sunlight as independent variable.

Comment: Then i did Multivariate analysis and added blue color as one variable and red color as another variable and subshine blue as indep. and subshine red as well, but i also guess this is wrong.

I would really appreciate your advice.

Comment: Can you post some sample data? It's hard to say without seeing what you are working with. A MANOVA might be appropriate for simultaneously testing for differences between colour indices though - just depends on the data you have.

Comment: A linear model seems fine to me, why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: @user2974951 Thank you for your answers. At first i thought it is, but when i got the results, i didnt know what to say! I mean the R^2 does not apply to neither of the 2 populations under study (red or blue) because both of them were included in the model.

Comment: @André.B Thank you for answering. But my indep. var is continuous as i mention above!

Comment: I don't understand, can you show us the code, what you have done and which step is not clear to you?